# Calculate difference in time between two rows

Tags: t-sql, datediff

I have a table with fields username and a lastUpdateDateTime.  If the user makes more than one entry into this table I would like to see what the difference is between the first and last entry is in minutes and seconds.  I thought I might use the function DATEDIFF but my database does not have a start date and end date as two separate fields.  Should I use a cursor to loop the results ordered by username?

Not sure how to do this.

HERE IS THE LATEST...

```
SELECT username,  
DATEDIFF(ss, MinDate, MaxDate) Assessment_Timespan,
AssessmentDate
FROM
(
SELECT storeID, username,
MIN(lastUpdateDateTime) MinDate,
MAX(lastUpdateDateTime) MaxDate, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), LastUpdateDateTime, 101) AS AssessmentDate
FROM Assessment
GROUP BY username, storeID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), LastUpdateDateTime, 101)
) src
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this. Which gets both the `min` and `max` value for each `username`.  Once you have that, then you can apply the [`DateDiff()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function to it:

```
select username,  
  datediff(ss, MinDate, MaxDate) DiffInSeconds
from
(
  select username,
    min(lastUpdateDateTime) MinDate,
    max(lastUpdateDateTime) MaxDate
  from yourtable
  group by username
) src
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d16c/4)

This gives you the difference in seconds, you can then format it in any manner that you need.

Comment: One more question.  So imagine this table also has a StoreID in it and I would like to know the time between the first entry and the last by store for each date.  For example a user goes to a store, makes several entries.  Then that user goes to another store and makes other entries.  I would like to know the time between their first and last entry for that user by store.

Comment: @brianhevans in the subquery you will add `StoreId` to the select list and the group by.  then you will be able to display this in the final result as well.

Comment: Now if I want to see the difference in time made for entries made by the user for each store I currently have that BUT if that user goes back to the same store the next day I want that to be a new result in my result set.  I tried adding my LastUpdateDateTime to my GROUP BY but that didn't get me what I was looking for.  Thoughts...

Comment: @brianhevans My suggestion would be to post a new question with the added details and some sample data.